# C++ crashes upon running but only some of the time

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, crash

This is my code. When I run some of the times it prints "1.5969" like I expect. About a third of the time it says the .exe file has stopped working and "windows is looking for a solution" type error. If I do not call test() it works 100% of the time. If I omit all of the code after test() but keep the call to test() it works 100% of the time. When the code is as written it works about a third of the time. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int test(int* b, int* c){
   ++*c;
   b[6] = 3;
   return b[6];
}

int main(){
    int* a;
    int c = 1;
    int* d = &c;
    a = new int[5];
    test(a, d);

    char a_[] = "1.5969 1.68 1.88";
    char* pEnd;
    double d1;
    d1 = strtod(a_,&pEnd);
    cout  << d1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `d1` and `a_` are not the best variable names you could imagine...

Comment: `a = new int[5];` creates an object with 5 elements. Accessing index 6 of that of course doesn't work.

Comment: You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all alike. Use meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Array index out of bounds in `test()`. Maximum space allocated is for 5 `int` but accessing the 7th number. This results in undefined behavior. Make sure index of `b` in `test()` is between 0 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

You access ot ouf bounds. `a = new int[5];` allocates 5 array elements. But `b[6]` access the 7th element of the array. Adapt your code like this:

```
int test(int* b, int* c){
   ++*c;
   b[6] = 3;
   return b[6];
}

int main(){
    int* a;
    int c = 1;
    int* d = &c;
    a = new int[7];
             // ^
    test(a, d);

    char a_[] = "1.5969 1.68 1.88";
    char *pEnd;
    double d1;
    d1 = strtod(a_,&pEnd);
    cout  << d1;
    return 0;
}
```